# Bootstrap Modal not focusing - shows additional element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Using Bootstrap 3 modals. Whenever I initiate a modal the code creates an additional `$('.modal-scrollable')` element with a higher `z-index` so that when the user scrolls, only the background scrolls (and not the modal). The user first has to click on the modal in order to scroll.

[image]

I developed this:

```
$('#modal-content').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal-scrollable').last().css('z-index', '1000');
    }, 100);
});
```

and it works great... but only the first time the modal appears, but then anytime afterwards I click to initiate the modal - the code doesn't initiate...why is that?

Can anyone help me so that the modal always focuses (the user doesn't need to click on the modal body first to focus it)??

**EDIT:** I think the issue lies in the [ModalManager](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.5/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js). It creates z-index's based on other element's z-indexes...the problem is I can't figure out which one is which...i went through all of them.

Comment: You should have made it clear that you're using the [jschr/bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) third-party library for the modals, as opposed to Bootstrap's default modals.